# Datatables 1.10 Ordering by an array of data

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable which gets data from an ajax source, it's currently ordered on column 4 descending. However I have an array of data which i'd like to order the table on which does not exist as a column.

```
oTable = $('#Table').DataTable({
                    "scrollX": true,
                    stateSave: false,
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": false,
                    "ajax": "scripts/SSP_enquiry.php",
                    select: true,
                    colReorder: true,
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false,
                            "targets": [9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
                        },

                        {className: "word", "targets": [1]}


                    ],


                    order: [4, 'desc'],
                    dom: '<"top">lrt<"bottom"pB><"clear">',
                    responsive: false,
                    buttons: [
                        'excel'
                    ]


                });
```

My function which uses Moment.JS to do a comparison between dates in the table (which exist in column 4) and todays date. It then pushes the difference in days in to an array called `dArray`.

My array has an Index for each value which should relate to the row in the table.

So what I want to do is use the index and value to sort the current table based on the values in `dArray`

```
 function dateGet() {

                var idx = oTable
                    .columns( 4 )
                    .data()
                    .eq( 0 );// Reduce the 2D array into a 1D array of data
                //console.log(idx);

                var dArray = [];
                var today = moment();

                $.each(idx, function(index,value) {
                    var tempDate = moment(value);
                    var deadlineDiff = tempDate.diff(today, 'days');
                    dArray.push(index,deadlineDiff);
                    console.log(dArray);
                })
            }
```

A sample of the `dArray`

```
[0, 6]
[1, 0]
[2, -0]
[3, -0]
[4, -1]
[5, -6]
[6, -7]
[7, -7]
[8, -11]
[9, -12]
[10, -12]
[11, -12]
[12, -13]
```

**UPDATE**

I've added a new column which values default to 0, so I now need to assign the values based on the array of deadline differences values. They need to match the corresponding row's ID.

`result[j][0]` will give me the ID in the array
`result[j][1]` will give me the difference value in the array

```
function dateGet() {

            var dArray = [];
            var today = moment();
            var ID = oTable
                .columns(0)
                .data()
                .eq(0);
            var dDate = oTable
                .columns(4)
                .data()
                .eq(0);// Reduce the 2D array into a 1D array of data


            $.each(dDate, function (index, value) {

                var tempDate = moment(value);
                var deadlineDiff = Math.abs(tempDate.diff(today, 'days'));
                dArray.push(deadlineDiff);

            });

            var result = $.map(ID, function (el, idx) {
                return [[el, dArray[idx]]];
            });

            oTable.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                var data = this.data();

                for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {

                    if (data[0] == result[j][0]) {
//in here the ID in the table and the ID in the array
// match, I need to iterate through rows and assign the value
//in the array to column 28's cell
                    }


                }


            });
        }
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion... in the render function for column 4 could you add a data-attribute to a span which contains your date? And then order on that rather than the date itself?

Comment: hmmm so you are suggesting, add the values in the array to the corresponding row/column index and then sort on data attribute. I have no idea whether I can do it, do you have an example?

Comment: @annoyingmouse is right, even better - simply return the array value when the `render()` method wants a `sort` or `filter` value.

Comment: Example added. I much prefer the granular control of `columns` rather than `columnDefs`. Should be easy enough to convert I guess though I've not tried.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you need (assuming that you want the difference to work irrespective of negative or positive:

```
$(function() {
    var example = $("#example").DataTable({
        columns: [{
            "title": "Released Date",
            "type": "int-diff",
            "render": function(d){
                var diff = Math.abs(moment().diff(moment(d, "DD/MM/YYYY"), 'days'));
                return $("<span></span>",{
                    "text": d + " (" + diff + ")",
                    "data-diff": diff
                }).prop("outerHTML");
            }
        }]
    });
});

jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "int-diff-pre": function(a) {
        return ~~$(a).data("diff");
    },
    "int-diff-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "int-diff-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Given a table like this:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>01/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>02/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>03/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>04/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>05/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>06/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>07/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>08/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>09/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14/04/2016</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xb9o7b7u/). Basically what we're doing is putting the difference between the date today and the date in the cell as a positive integer in a span as a data attribute with the date the content of the span. Then we use that data attribute to sort with rather than the content of the span.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can see what you've done, I have 28 columns some which require columnDefs to set classes/visibility etc. I've changed the structure slightly so that I have an extra column called deadlineDateDifference. initially set to 0. Im looping through each row, checking whether the row ID matches the ID in my array, all I need now is a way of targetting that row and column 28's data to change it to the value in the array Ill update with code.

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped.

Comment: I don't suppose you know how I can achieve the above using the extra code that i've supplied? So that the column is sortable as well?

Comment: Perhaps work up a JSFiddle to illustrate your issue?

Comment: I think I have it now, thanks for the help

`oTable.cell({row: rowIdx, column: 28}).data(result[j][1]);` 

Seemed to do the trick. Then just redrew the table at the end of the function and sorted by that column now the data was in the column with correct row.

 `oTable.order([28, 'asc']).draw();`